# Use Toolbar With Tab Layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I had created an Android Chatting Application in that I want to add new Material Designs like Toolbar with tab layout, etc.

The application is developed in Eclipse and I tried to add Toolbar layout, it raises error.

I updated the SDK to Android 5.1.1 and also imported the AppCompact library.

Any help will be appreciated.

I using below code for sample test:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I found this code from below link:
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Thanks.

Comment: post your code and error that you got

Comment: @DroidDev, please see my edited question.

Comment: Error is : "android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout" not found.

Comment: have you imported design library ?

Comment: Why... would you still use Eclipse?

Comment: @Marko, Because from begging I get training on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to used android design support library for tab layout because its in built in android sdk. This library contains different ui like as floating action button, tab layout, textinput layout, etc...See below link of android developer blog.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Use below code:

```
     <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lytSearchBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/fivedp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" // layout_scrollFlags for scroll layout
                    android:visibility="visible">

        </Linearout>
         </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvOrderList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/lytSearchBar"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/tendp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I am using android-support-v7-appcompat in my app. Is it right?

Comment: yes it is right but for tab layout you have to add design support library jar.

Comment: Do you have any sample example in eclipse?

Comment: I found many examples but all are developed in Android Studio, when I tried to convert in Eclipse it raises lots of errors. :(

Comment: no i have to used android studio but its easy only add design support jar in  eclipse and you have to used tab layout as per android developer blog example

Comment: I wants to make profile screen like whatsapp profile in my app.

Comment: Let me try once again.

Comment: Hi Sweta , Just Refer this Github library :: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: first you specify you want to implement tab layout or profile screen like whatsapp ?

Comment: The main problem is I don't have experience of Android Studio.

Comment: ok but you have to add only design support library jar in eclipse

Comment: this is the path of design support library : D:\Android\Sdk\extras\android\compatibility\design\libs

Comment: Now I am getting error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scrollFlags'

Comment: in android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: have you add design support library

Comment: @Darshan, Yes, I added the design support library.

Comment: @DarshanMistry, Thanks for helping me, its working for me. There are some library issues in my project, which I found in sdk/extra/android/support/v7 folder.